Application images are not showing of the Angular application after deployment on Azure
I have an Angular application that I deployed on the prem( Window Serve), and it is working fine. but once I deploy that application on Azure using the app service, then images are not showing. 
On Azure, content/type is showing text/html.
enter image description here
On Prem, content/type is showing image/png
enter image description here
Images are needed to be displayed.

"On Azure, content/type is showing text/html." -> The image in your first link (https://i.sstatic.net/LYr0o.png) clearly shows Content-Type: image/png. Just like the second one.

The following are the steps I took to deploy an Angular app to Azure Static Web Apps using Azure DevOps for your reference.

I am using the sample code here. Import the repo to my Azure repo. I added a home.png file to index.html file.

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <p>This is a png:</p>
  <img src="assets/home.png" alt="Home Image">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>


Create a static web app following the steps here. A DevOps pipeline will be created automatically to deploy the app.

Then I can see the image shown as expected.



